# How to interrupt boost::this_thread in c++

Tags: c++, boost-thread

In my application i have given sleep of 10 sec. I have given sleep using boost::this_thread::sleep function.
Is there any possible way to interrupt boost::this_thread::sleep function.?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit, should you answer beeing funny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`sleep()` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep):

> **Throws:**
>      `boost::thread_interrupted` if the current thread of execution is interrupted.
>
> **Notes:**
>      `sleep()` is one of the predefined [*interruption points*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points).

So what you need to do in your thread is to put the `sleep()` call in a `try-catch`, and catch `boost::thread_interrupted`. Then call [`interrupt()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt) on the thread object to interrupt the sleep.

---

By the way, also from the [`sleep` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep):

> **Warning**
>
> DEPRECATED since 3.0.0.
>
> Use [`sleep_for()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep_for) and [`sleep_until()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep_until) instead.

Comment: hey @Joachim Pileborg  i m using sleep function from "boost::this_thread" which does not have interrupt API and my requirement is to use "boost::this_thread" so is there any way to interrupt sleep.

Comment: @user3721279 `boost::this_thread::sleep` is, as I quoted from the link in my answer, an *interruption* point. Please read the links provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can interrupt the `sleep` function using `interrupt()`.

You have to enable interruption for your thread, when its sleeping, you can use the interrupt function.

Boost hast a very nice short tutorial online regarding this, have a look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption

Answer (score 0):

> I have given sleep using boost::this_thread::sleep function. Is there any possible way to interrupt boost::this_thread::sleep function.?

Not as such, but it is not difficult to implement it, in terms of `boost::this_thread::sleep`:

```
void sleep_for(boost::posix_time::milliseconds interval, std::atomic<bool>& interrupted)
{
    static const auto resolution = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
    ptime end_time(microsec_clock::local_time()) + interval;

    while( !interrupted.load() )
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(resolution);
        if(microsec_clock::local_time() > end_time)
            break;
    }
}
```

Client code thread 1:

```
std::atomic<bool>& interrupt = false;

void f() {
    sleep_for(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200), interrupt);
}
```

Client code thread 2:

```
interrupt.store(true); /// will cause thread 1 to be interrupted, if called
                       /// during execution of sleep_for.
```